# fill in missing fields using import csv

Tags: python

My data set looks like the below:

```
W000000457,,
,9/18/2016 11:28,37
,4/21/2016 0:07,54
,11/5/2016 12:05,42
,7/14/2016 15:43,54
W000000457 - Count,,100
2069320,,
,12/10/2016 0:22,12
,9/25/2016 14:07,28
,1/24/2016 6:54,59
2069320 - Count,,100
111,,
,1/16/2016 10:25,58
,6/11/2016 4:17,43
,4/21/2016 7:56,47
,3/17/2016 3:48,20
111 - Count,,100
```

The columns are ID, Date, Value.  I do 2 main cleansing/massaging of the data.

1) Using the ID in row 1, I populate the below rows
2) Remove any rows with "Count" in the row[0]

My goal is to get something like this:

```
W000000457,9/18/2016 11:28,37
W000000457,4/21/2016 0:07,54
W000000457,11/5/2016 12:05,42
W000000457,7/14/2016 15:43,54
2069320,12/10/2016 0:22,12
2069320,9/25/2016 14:07,28
2069320,1/24/2016 6:54,59
111,1/16/2016 10:25,58
111,6/11/2016 4:17,43
111,4/21/2016 7:56,47
111,3/17/2016 3:48,20
```

This is the code I have so far:

```
import csv
    with open('data.txt','rb') as f_in:
        reader = csv.reader(f_in)
        row = next(reader)
        last_row = row
        for row in reader:
            row = [x if x else y for x, y in zip(row, last_row)]
            if 'COUNT' not in row[0].upper():
                print row
            last_row = row
```

This gets me close but the problem is handling the records inbetween the different ID's example:

```
W000000457,,
,1/24/2016 6:54,59
2069320 - Count,,100
111,,
,1/16/2016 10:25,58
```

Will become (using my code):

```
W000000457,1/24/2016 6:54,59
111,1/24/2016 6:54,100
111,1/16/2016 10:25,58
```

The first instance of ID 111 is not a real value that was carried from the previous existing values.

Or in the example above i get:

```
W000000457,9/18/2016 11:28,37
W000000457,4/21/2016 0:07,54
W000000457,11/5/2016 12:05,42
W000000457,7/14/2016 15:43,54
**2069320,7/14/2016 15:43,100**
2069320,12/10/2016 0:22,12
2069320,9/25/2016 14:07,28
2069320,1/24/2016 6:54,59
**111,1/24/2016 6:54,100**
111,1/16/2016 10:25,58
111,6/11/2016 4:17,43
111,4/21/2016 7:56,47
111,3/17/2016 3:48,20
```

fields in ** are fake values

Any ideas on how I should handle this?

I was thinking of removing the first instance of each ID or looking for a way to only replace [0] of my csvreader instead of every field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With csv type data, use [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/).

Reading the data:

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO('''W000000457,,
,9/18/2016 11:28,37
,4/21/2016 0:07,54
,11/5/2016 12:05,42
,7/14/2016 15:43,54
W000000457 - Count,,100
2069320,,
,12/10/2016 0:22,12
,9/25/2016 14:07,28
,1/24/2016 6:54,59
2069320 - Count,,100
111,,
,1/16/2016 10:25,58
,6/11/2016 4:17,43
,4/21/2016 7:56,47
,3/17/2016 3:48,20
111 - Count,,100'''), names=['col1', 'col2', 'col3'])
```

Forward fill NaN items in the first column:

```
df['col1'] = df['col1'].fillna(method='ffill')
```

Filter out items where the first column contains 'Count'

```
df = df[~df['col1'].str.contains('Count')]
```

Drop rows that still have NaN:

```
df = df.dropna()
```

Final result:

```
          col1             col2  col3
1   W000000457  9/18/2016 11:28  37.0
2   W000000457   4/21/2016 0:07  54.0
3   W000000457  11/5/2016 12:05  42.0
4   W000000457  7/14/2016 15:43  54.0
7      2069320  12/10/2016 0:22  12.0
8      2069320  9/25/2016 14:07  28.0
9      2069320   1/24/2016 6:54  59.0
12         111  1/16/2016 10:25  58.0
13         111   6/11/2016 4:17  43.0
14         111   4/21/2016 7:56  47.0
15         111   3/17/2016 3:48  20.0
```